# get list of cities to show in a web page

Tags: php, zend-framework, geo

I want to show a list of all Indian cities in a dropdown in a web page, for the user to choose from in a registration form. I went to http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/ and download the relevant zip which contained a huge text file containing the cities. There does not seem to be an option to dump this cities data in sql format. So, I will either have to parse the text file and then import into my database, or will have to search some other collection in sql format (I actually did this, but found that they all needed paid accounts for access). Anyways, it does not look like a good idea to me to present a huge list of cities in a dropdown, since it would take several MBs of data to be loaded just for displaying that web-page. Is there any free web service API that I can query using AJAX for auto-completion to get cities?

Comment: I highly doubt it, that is rather niche. Why not import the cities and just write your own?

Comment: Parse the text file and share the SQL on github :)

Comment: You could use the text file as a suggestion resource for autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

[Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities) may be of use

Or you could convert the data to xml and then use that, [there are tools available](https://github.com/yosoyadri/GeoNames-XML-Builder). It is then possible to convert xml to sql but the actual implementation would depend on which language and database is your preference.